# Flutter First Letter Bloc Builder error when no name

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

In my Main Menu, I have a circle box shape that displays the user's first letter.

If a user does not have a first name, it is showing a grey box. How do I get it to display a blank circle instead? As you can see by my code I have tried an or function "." but that doesn't work.

```
 child: Container(
                    height: 130,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                                        bottomLeft: Radius.circular(30.0),
                                        bottomRight: Radius.circular(30.0)),
                            color: Theme.of(context).canvasColor,
                      boxShadow: [
                        BoxShadow(
                          color: Colors.black12,
                          offset: Offset(5, 5),
                          blurRadius: 10,
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left:40.0),
                      child: Row(children: [
                        FittedBox(
                          fit: BoxFit.contain,
                          alignment: Alignment.center,
                          child: Container(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          gradient: LinearGradient(
          colors: [Color(0xffff8a93), Color(0xffffbf81)],
          begin: Alignment.topLeft,
          end: Alignment.bottomRight),
          boxShadow: [
],
          shape: BoxShape.circle,
        ),
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(30.0),
        child: BlocBuilder(
                                cubit: BlocProvider.of<UserBloc>(context),
                                builder: (context, User user) {
                                  return Text(
                                    (user.email == null || user.firstName == null)
                                        ? "."
                                        : '${user.firstName[0].toUpperCase()}',
                                    style: GoogleFonts.roboto( textStyle:TextStyle(
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
                                      fontSize: 50,
                                      color: Colors.white,
                                    ),),
                                    textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                                  );
                                }),
  ),
),
```

[image]

Comment: Include the code of the parent widget that creates the circle.

Comment: I have updated the code